# Leaflet: How to get pixel position of a lat lng after zoom, before zoom begins

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, leaflet, mapbox

I want to transform:translate an SVG group to a latLng pixel position, and maintain that position after zoom.

I've tried:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(e) {...});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8dnsrnk/15/

But obviously that only fires after the zoom, so the SVG doesn't move as fluidly as, say, the marker does.

I've tried looking at the source to see how the a Leaflet marker is repositioned, as that is essentially the behaviour I'm trying to emulate, but to no avail. If someone has another suggestion for achieving this effect, I'd be interested! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for the "zoomanim" event and get the new center of your circle by doing the following:

```
var coord = map._latLngToNewLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(51.5, -0.087), e.zoom, e.center);
```

The animation of the marker is performed by CSS, specifically the class selected ".leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-animated" (look in leaflet.css).  You need to do something similar for your SVG.  Instead of setting the "transform" attribute on your SVG, set a "transform" style and then define a transition animation for that style in your CSS.

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inpursuit/mcatbrhk/1/

Comment: wow..thanks very much, I would never have got that! :)) I started messing with `.project([latlng])`, so kind of on the right path, but had no idea about this hidden function. 
Also, I guess the transform is moved to style rather than attr so you can exactly match the transition used by Leaflet, and therefore they move in tandem?

Comment: Yea, the transform is done in the CSS so that you can customize it if you want without having to change the leaflet source code.  And the fact that it's done in the CSS makes it easier to do what you wanted to do :)